# Retorno de tabelas com hasMany - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Em um relacionamento `belongsToMany`, quando transformo o resultado em `json` acaba retornando o campo `_joinData`.

Teria alguma forma de não trazer ele na consulta ou não exibir no `json` utilizando alguma opção do Cake?

**`JSON` exemplo:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Produto Teste",
  "slug": "produto-teste",
  "cover": null,
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "Bebida",
      "_joinData": {
        "category_id": 1,
        "id": 5,
        "product_id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Roupa",
      "_joinData": {
        "category_id": 2,
        "id": 6,
        "product_id": 1
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

*Edit: Estou utilizando a versão 3.2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ocultar a exibição deste campo acrescentando-o na propriedade [`_hidden`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#hiding-properties) da sua entidade, assim:

```
protected $_hidden = ['_joinData'];
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado :)